# How to connect Car_type, Model and Mark Car Laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have a type of car, brand and model table. When a user chooses type car, he gets Audi, Bmw, Mercedes. When choosing Audi, it only gets models for Audi etc A1, A2, A3. If the bmw win gets X6, X4 models. I have three table 
1. Type with Car. (For now only Car latter will be maybe bike)
2. Mark
3. Model

How to connect this three table with Laravel eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

```
--- car_types ---
id        name
1         sedan
2         hatchback
3         sport
4         suv

-- car_brands ---
id        name
1         bmw
2         mercedes
3         audi

-- car_models --
id        brand_id    model_name  car_type
1         3           A1          1
2         3           A2          1
3         3           A3          1
4         3           Q7          4
5         1           X5          4
6         1           X6          4
7         1           X7          4
8         2           AMG         3
9         3           A1          2


-- cars --
id model_id brand_id model_year name             ...other fields
1  1        3        2018       Audi A1 1.0 2018
2  3        3        2017       Audi A3 1.6 2017

on cars table brand_id* is optional foreign key as shortcut for reaching car's brand.
```

Relationships:

1. A Car Type **hasMany** Car Models. (foreign: car_models.car_type > car_types.id)
2. A Car Brand **hasMany** Car Models. (foreign: car_models.brand_id > car_brands.id)
3. A Car **belongsTo** A Car Model. (foreign: cars.model_id > car_models.id)
4. A Car **belongsTo** A Car Brand. (foreign: cars.brand_id > car_brands.id)

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have the model

**CarType** for the Cars Types table
**CarBrand** for car_brands table and
**CarModel** for car_models table

You can use Eloquent: Relationships to achieve this

In your CarType Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CarType extends Model
  {
    /**
     * Get the brands for the car .
     */
    public function brands()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CarBrand');
  }
}
```

In your CarBrand Model, you can get the car type that a brand belongs to using

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class CarBrand extends Model
 {
   /**
   * Get the car that owns the brand.
   */
  public function carType()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CarType');
  }
}
```

for instance, you can do

```
$car = Car->find(1); // to get car with ID 1.
$brands = $car->brands; // brands of the selected car. You can loop through now
```

Also, for the brand, you can do

```
$brand = Brand->find(1) // For Brand ID 1
$car = $brand->carType;
```

You can check [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Okey but i have yet car_type?

Comment: If you just go through the example I gave above and read the relationship document, you will get it right